# Number of unique elements in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

If I have a vector of floats as {1.2,1.2,1.2,1.3,1.4} and I have to find out the number of unique elements, how can I do it?

I am new to C++ and I don't really know how to use iterators. Thanks!

Edit:
I did something like this:

```
sort(arra.begin(),arra.end());
    vector <float>::iterator it = arra.begin();
    while ( it != arra.end() )
    {
        temp1 = *it;
        cout<<temp1<<"\n";
        it++;
        while (*it == temp1)
        {
            it++;
            cout<<*it<<"\n";
        }
        count++;
    }
```

But this gives a WA.

Comment: give it your best shot and we'll help. First sort the vector then iterate through it and count the transitions to a different value than the previous one.

Comment: I added what I did, but this gives a wrong value.

Comment: @Elliot on what input?

Answer (score 10):

One of approaches is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 };

    std::cout << "Number of unique elements is "
              << std::set<double>( v.begin(), v.end() ).size()
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Number of unique elements is 3
```

If the vector is already sorted and not empty you can use the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 };

    auto n = 1 + std::inner_product( std::next( v.begin() ), v.end(), 
                                     v.begin(), size_t( 0 ),
                                     std::plus<size_t>(), 
                                     std::not_equal_to<double>() );

    std::cout << "Number of unique elements is " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or straightforward approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 };

    size_t n = 0;

    if ( v.begin() != v.end() )
    {
        ++n;
        for ( auto current = v.begin(), prev = v.begin(); 
             ++current != v.end(); ++prev )
        {
            if ( !( *prev < *current ) && !( *current < *prev ) ) ++n;
        }           
    }

    std::cout << "Number of unique elements is " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @InQusitive Why can not float numbers be compared?

Comment: Will this method not work if the numbers are perfect integers and not floats?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: because of the precision, I am not talking abt this particular situation, in general.

Comment: @InQusitive You may define you own comparator.

Comment: @InQusitive *Unique* implies that the elements are exacly the same, so precision is not an issue here.

Comment: @Elliot I do not know about "pefect integers" but the method will work with integers.

Comment: You can compare float numbers InQuisitive but they need to be exactly the same to match.  If you try to match 1.21 with 1.22, it'll fail.  In order to do that you need a lamba or function that takes an epsilon such that they're compared to within a given error, which is quite easy to write.

Answer (score 3):

If it's OK to modify the vector (or you can make a copy of it):

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
auto uniqCnt = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()) - v.begin();
```

Note that this may not work for floats because they don't represent the numbers exactly (but then you have to clarify what you mean by "unique elements" with respect to floats)

Comment: I think it should work as well as the `std::set` solution posted by @Vlad

Comment: This one modifies the set though doesn't it.  Still a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work.

```
std::vector< float > vec = { 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.3f, 1.4f };
int unique_elements = 0;

{
    std::vector< float > used;
    for ( std::vector< float >::const_iterator it = vec.cbegin(); it != vec.cend(); ++it )
    {
        if ( std::find( used.cbegin(), used.cend(), *it ) == used.cend() )
        {
            used.push_back( *it );
            ++unique_elements;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the input vector is sorted, you can try `std::binary_search`

Answer (score 0):

Instead is using `vector` use `set`. It always keeps the unique element in it.

Read this [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) for how to find out unique element in vector.

Answer (score 0):

following works as well :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<double> doublevector;

int main()
{
    doublevector v = { 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 };

    sort(v.begin(), v.end()); //not needed if you know vector is sorted

    int nbrUnique = 0;
    if (v.size() == 1) nbrUnique = 1;
    else{
        nbrUnique = 1;
        for (doublevector::iterator it = v.begin(); it < v.end() - 1; ++it){
            if ((*it) != *(it + 1)) nbrUnique++;
        }
    }
    cout << nbrUnique << endl;

    return 0;
}
```